# Azure Instance change deleted files

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

I am new to windows Azure, I am using 6month subscription plan with 1 VM  yesterday instance of my VM changed & my files from root folder are deleted, how can I restore that files and how can I prevennt this in near future.

Answer (score 2):

Azure PAAS instances aren't meant to store anything persistently on *local* disk since it may/will be wiped regularly when the instances are automatically replaced.

For best performance, you could store the files in [blob storage](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/blob-storage/) where they can be accessed by any server using your storage account instead of just the single machine.

If you *really* need persistent file storage, you can [attach blob storage as a local disk](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/how-to-guides/attach-a-disk/) and store your data there. Note though that the disk will only be accessible by one instance at a time.

As for the files stored on the local file system when the instance was replaced, unless you have a backup, I know of no way to restore them.

[This link is a good read regarding various storage options in Azure](http://blog.codingoutloud.com/2011/06/12/azure-faq-can-i-write-to-the-file-system-on-windows-azure/) that gives much more details than this space allows for.

Comment: Thanks, but my application is related to images management system. End user can upload his images & share. I will use 5 VM instance when system get live, so can you tell me what is best approach to save all images.

Comment: @TarunMathur Images are a very good fit for blob storage. Anything stored there can be accessed with very good scalability from all instances, and (if you wish) you can later connect [the Azure CDN](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/cdn/) to distribute the images right from blob storage without even involving your instances.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a virtual machine (IaaS):

- Add a data disk and store files there, and not on the OS disk
- You are responsible for making backups yourself

If you are using cloud services (PaaS):

- Don't store data on the machine itself, use that only for cache, temporary data
- Add a data disk and mount it, if it's a single server
- Use blob storage if the data is used from multiple hosts